# How many blades should a decorative windmill have?

Tags: windmill

I have decided that my next yard project is going to be a decorative windmill.  I am NOT going to pump water or generate electricity with the windmill, I just want it to turn in the wind and look nice.  It will be (approx) three feet in diameter and be around ten feet off the ground.

I live in a tree filled part of Atlanta, Georgia, which means that the wind will be pretty low.

There seem to be two options - a three blade system, which will generate a high rpm, as detailed here [Wind Generator](http://makeprojects.com/Project/Wind-Generator/9/1#.T-uRVbWe7w1) or the [traditional farmer's windmill](http://www.backwoodshome.com/articles2/ainsworth90.html),

From what I've read, both options assume a load of some sort, either a generator or a water pump, and a high wind.  I will have no load on the mill and poor wind.

Does anyone know which of these will work better in a low wind, no load situation?  My goal is to have the blades turn as much of the time as possible.

Comment: Seems awfully subjective.  This is about it "looking nice", right?

Comment: Good point - I clarified the goal.

Comment: If there's no load, and the axle/bearings are efficient, then it's likely purely an aesthetic call.

Comment: All the traditional ones I saw in Holland had 4 blades. Knock your socks off and have as many as you want!!!